# How can I recover my Empathy Internet messaging keyring password? It asks me at starting it

Tags: 10.10, gnome-keyring

I forgot my empathy internet messaging  password..
now i am not able to login on emapthy it is asking me everytime for keyring password.. is there any way to get my password back?

Answer (score 3):

Try looking at seahorse:
Open a terminal and type:

```
seahorse
```

[image]